# How to enable Application Logs in Azure for Net Core 2 App?

Tags: c#, azure, logging, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to enable application logs in azure.
I have a dummy Net Core 2 App running in an appService in azure.

and basically my goal is to see the trace messages in the log stream and in the application log files but I have not found the right way to do this.

One of the challenge I have found reading other posts is that they assume a web config in place.

[image: Home Controller]
  [image: Configuration In Azure]
  [image: Startup.cs]

Answer (score 12):

The documentation for ASP.NET Core 2.2 is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#logging-in-azure).

Firstly, enable Application Logging and choose the appropriate level:

[image: switch on application logging]

This may be all you need to do to diagnose any problems. But if you want log messages and see them, install the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices NuGet package.

Then, configure logging:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Now you can inject and use ILogger:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    this.logger = logger;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    logger.LogWarning("Starting up");
```

Then in the Azure App Service, click on Log stream:
[image: Log stream]

Answer (score 3):

Run `dotnet add package EntityFramework Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices` to install logging extension to your project.

Program.cs file for reference:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
             {
                 logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                 logging.AddConsole();
                 logging.AddDebug();
                 logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
             })
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices/)" package and then register the logging provider for azure using code below.

```
 loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics( 
    new AzureAppServicesDiagnosticsSettings 
    {
          OutputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz} [{Level}] {RequestId}-{SourceContext}: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}" 
    } 
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get answer from this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/26/asp-net-core-logging/). The following is the snippet from the blog.

> Setting up logging in an ASP.NET Core app doesn’t require much code. ASP.NET Core new project templates already setup some basic logging providers with this code in the Startup.Configure method:

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging")); 
loggerFactory.AddDebug();
```

[image]