# How to configure .NET Core Azure logging

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I have uploaded a very simple app in Azure on .NET Core 2.1.3.
Configured the App Service logging as follows:
[image]

the code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}

public class Startup
{
    private readonly ILogger<Startup> logger;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Startup> logger)
    {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // Commented lines doesn't affect ...              
        //loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        // loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

        loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();

        this.logger.LogInformation("Loading::::::::::::::::::");


        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation("OnRequest::::::::::::::::::");
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Loading...");
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that the logging works locally, but no in azure. If I open `/Log Files/Application/afg4322-201809062011.log` my messages `OnRequest::::::::::::::::::` and `Loading::::::::::::::::::` didn't appear there. Currently the logic catches all requests and simply writes a log message.
Also I've installed `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices` and troubleshot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/azure-apps/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-2.1#aspnet-core-module-stdout-log nothing working.

How to log a message in Azure app ? Maybe I'm missing some simple setting?

The `applicationSettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
      "IncludeScopes": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

I've checked this articles
- [Asp.net Core azure web app logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398453/asp-net-core-azure-web-app-logging)
- [How to enable Application Logs in Azure for Net Core 2 App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46996730/how-to-enable-application-logs-in-azure-for-net-core-2-app)

I'm trying to avoid suggestion from `Ilya Chernomordik` where he says to set `<aspNetCore stdoutLogEnabled="true" />` and modify `SourceSwitch`. I think it's not the correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A found a solution.
The app was published in `Release` Mode - so I've added an `appsettings.Production.json`:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

And changed my code as follows:

```
var l = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();
l.LogInformation("OnRequest:::::::::Info:::::::::");
l.LogDebug("OnRequest:::::::::Debug:::::::::");
l.LogError("OnRequest::::::::::::::Error::::");
l.LogWarning("OnRequest::::::::::::Warning::::::");
l.LogTrace("OnRequest:::::::::::::Trace:::::");
l.LogCritical("OnRequest::::::::::::::Critical::::");
await context.Response.WriteAsync("Loading...");
```

Instead using the field `logger`, I get a logger from `loggerFactory`.

Now a receive all messages in `Streaming Logs` in Azure portal:

`2018-09-06 19:10:01.449 +00:00 [Information] WebApp.Startup: OnRequest:::::::::Info:::::::::
2018-09-06 19:10:01.449 +00:00 [Debug] WebApp.Startup: OnRequest:::::::::Debug:::::::::
2018-09-06 19:10:01.449 +00:00 [Error] WebApp.Startup: OnRequest::::::::::::::Error::::
2018-09-06 19:10:01.449 +00:00 [Warning] WebApp.Startup: OnRequest::::::::::::Warning::::::
2018-09-06 19:10:01.449 +00:00 [Trace] WebApp.Startup: OnRequest:::::::::::::Trace:::::
2018-09-06 19:10:01.449 +00:00 [Critical] WebApp.Startup: OnRequest::::::::::::::Critical::::`